# Populating a jquery slider with images fetched from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have created a page, where using PHP a div is populated with images fetched from a database like this:

```
div style="display: none" id="templates" class="row">
            <?php
            while ($one = $templatesk->fetch()) {
                ?>
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2">
                    <a  class="thumbnail" data-price="<?= $one['price'] ?>" data-id="<?= $one['id'] ?>">
                        <img id="imgTemp" onclick= "changeImage('../files/templates/blank/<? echo($one['id'])?>.jpg', '../files/shapes/<? echo($one['tsize'])?>.png');" src="/files/templates/example/<?= $one['id'] ?>.jpg" alt="<?= $one['titlep'] ?>">
                    </a>
                </div>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </div>
```

But the div has a small number of images that can fit the screen so I desided using a jquery slider, except that all sliders use pre-defined images as sources, one example being this:

```
<div id="lista2" class="als-container">
    <span class="als-prev"><img src="images/thin_top_arrow_333.png" alt="prev" title="previous" /></span>
    <div class="als-viewport">
        <div class="als-wrapper">
            <div class="als-item"><img src="images/als-images/calculator.png" alt="calculator" title="calculator" />calculator</div>
            <div class="als-item"><img src="images/als-images/light_bulb.png" alt="light bulb" title="light bulb" />light bulb</div>
            <div class="als-item"><img src="images/als-images/card.png" alt="card" title="card" />card</div>
    </div>
    <span class="als-next"><img src="images/thin_bottom_arrow_333.png" alt="next" title="next" /></span>
</div>
```

I have tried many combinations and I get the most one image to be loaded, is there any way I can load all images?

Comment: I'm trying to understand your problem but, maybe for my bad knowledge of english, I don't understand what is it... Could you try to explain better?

Comment: @Frogmouth Yes, I have several images on inside my file-server. They are loaded in my normal HTML <div> tag using the code I've written first. Now, I want to use a jquery slider to do the same function, to load all the images inside it. I can't write the source of every image, because they are many. I want them to be loaded inside the slider with the help of a javascript/jquery function

Comment: ... wait... example: in your DB you have 150 images, with php loop want to load and print only 10 of them and when user does something (tell me what is this "something") jquery loads other X images...via ajax maybe. Is what you need to do?

Comment: I want to load all the images from the database into the slider. The user chooses a category and the images of this category appear. I've only added one category as an example, the code I've written first.